# Parsing irregular c++ prototypes

Tags: c++, parsing, header, prototype-programming

I am trying to build a program that parses and lists the content of header files. So far, so good, I found it easy parsing and listing headers I wrote, but when I started parsing cross platform API headers things got messy.

My current approach is rather simplistic, here is a pseudocode example of parsing the following function:

```
void foo(int a);

void is a type, so we are dealing with instancing a type
foo is the name of that type
foo is followed by brackets, meaning it is a function of type void named foo
   int is a type...
   a is the name of that type instance
foo is a function of type void that takes one parameter of type int named a
```

However, when I got into bigger and more complex headers I stumbled upon somewhat irregular prototypes, involving macros and god knows what. An example:

```
GLAPI void APIENTRY glEvalCoord1d( GLdouble u );
```

GLAPI and APIENTRY are platform dependent macros. Which kind of spoils my simple parsing scheme, since it expects the name of an object to follow its type. Those two macros happen to translate to either __stdcall, __declspec(dllimport) or extern but in theory they could mean anything, with their meaning being unclear until compile time.

How to write my parser so it can deal with such scenarios and not get confused? The macros themselves are defined at an earlier stage, so the parser can be aware GLAPI and APIENTRY are macros so they can simply be ignored, is this the way to go? Naturally this is just one of the many variations of irregularities the parser may stumble upon parsing through different headers, so any general techniques of how to deal with the parsing of any "legal" header content are welcome.

Comment: No, I don't need any advice. Cheers, though.

Comment: I am sorry, there was an exclamation mark "Need an advice!" but for some reason the site changed it to ? and even after I edited my post it still put a question mark... Weird but I supposed since I am posting a question the question mark is by default... Let me guess, you tried to edit it and failed as well??? :)

Comment: Hah, you're right.. it does appear to re-write trailing exclamation marks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-mark-to-question-mark

Comment: You do realize your program can invoke the preprocessor, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any real alternative to expanding the macros before you parse, at least if you want process header files with the same complexity as Microsoft's, or any other header files associated with a compiler system that has been around for 10 years or more.

The unpreprocessed source code is NOT C; it is simply unpreprocessed source code.  The macros (and prepreprocessor conditionals which you surprising didn't mention) can edit the apparant source in not arbitrary but spectacularly complex fashion.  And you can't often know what the macros used, or conditionals expanded, unless you process the #includes as well.

You can get GCC to do preprocessor expansion for you, and then parse it. That would be far
the easiest way to approach this.

That still leaves the problem of parsing real C code, with all the complexities of declarators, and ambiguities in fragments suchas  **T X;** where the meaning of the statement depends on the declaration of T.   To parse the headers accurately, you need a full C parser.

Our [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) can do full preprocessing, or you can invoke it a mode in which some macros are expanded, and some are not.   By tuning this set, you often parse such headers without exapanding every macro.  Preprocessor conditionals are much more difficult, because they can occur at inconvenient (unstructured) places.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the name and signature of functions, then a simple search and replace for macros should be sufficient.

*However*, you need to check if a macro contains keywords (like the return value). This may be possible by stripping macro definitions of every but keywords as they are defined, but tracking them and using a simple preprocessor will be necessary.

The platform dependent keywords, such as `__declspec` and `__attribute__` have very limited syntax and there are only a few of them, so specifically removing those is possible.

You may want to take a look at how doxygen handles this, because it does almost exactly what you want and does handle macros. It allows a list of macros to be expanded as defined, and ones that should be expanded to a custom value. You could adapt that to expand `__declspec(x)` to nothing, and expand all others to their defined value by default.

This certainly isn't foolproof, but a search and replace is about the simplest functional solution you'll get. You need to follow the standard C++ preprocessor rules, which aren't terribly complex, with additional macros (const, declspec, etc) to strip extra attributes, and parse the final results.